# What is the name for a group of words that share antonyms but do not necessarily equate?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, collective-nouns

An example of this would be the concepts of humility and shame, which are both antonyms of pride, but are not synonyms or necessarily the same. What is the word that describes words that have this relationship as having common opposites?

For example "precipitate" has the antonyms, "dissolve" and "evaporate," but dissolve and evaporate are not the same.

There was a similar post on here asking about words that have multiple antonyms, but I am asking about the multiple antonyms of a given such word, termed a "polysemous antonym" in the post I refer to here.
It was mentioned that in the various senses of the word, "black," the antonym could either be white or red. antonyms of "right" are askew, left, wrong, obtuse, acute, incorrect, immoral, responsibility, topple, and worsen.

What do you call the terms white and red as relating to black, or sit and lie as relating to stand, or inflame and obscure and cloudy and opaque and translucent and uncertain and fail and blocked and colliding in relation to clear?

When I looked it up on Bing, I got mostly answers like "auto-antonym" and "contronym" and "janus word" which all describe an individual given word based on its multiple meanings, those meanings being contrary. the word I'm looking for should be similar to "synonym," "antonym," "homophone," "similar word," and "opposite" in function and in syntax. That is to say, given a set of words that satisfy the condition, you could say those words are collectively [noun[s]] of/to each other. Also acceptable would be an adjective describing the relationship between these words, similar to how "similar" describes things that resemble each other, or how "family" describes people who are related by blood.

Example sentences would be:

> Because mad and sad are both opposites of happy, 'mad' and 'sad' are [plural noun].
> The words, 'slim,' 'meat,' and 'lean' are all opposites of 'fat,' and are thus [adjective[s]] (to each other) because of it.

The post I mentioned:
[Is there a term for words which are the opposites of more than one word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447506/is-there-a-term-for-words-which-are-the-opposites-of-more-than-one-word)

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that "opposite" is ill-defined. Most words have no opposites, or have too many, on various scales. (What's the opposite of "collie", for instance? Or _rock_ -- either noun or verb?) [Negation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is a vastly complicated subject.

Comment: If the words are related only by the shared antonym, you might be stuck with the prosaic "they are antonyms of ___".

Comment: How is "mad" an antonym of happy? "Mad" and "happy" are mutually exclusive, but they aren't antonyms.